# Кау обойти Access denied?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то обойти блокировку запроса? Отправляю 300 запросов одним запросом, некоторые приходят, а вот некоторые не приходят, вместо них сообщение Access Denied.

Comment: отправлять поменьше и пореже

Comment: Наверняка у API которым Вы пользуетесь, есть некоторое ограничение на количество запросов в определенный временной отрезок. Потому наверное нужно постараться делать поменьше запросов к API (если можно условно получить данные определенного количества пользователей в одном запросе, то стоило бы об этом подумать), ну и результаты стоило бы кешировать.

Comment: Я апи не использую + у них его нет. Я отправляю в тупую пост запросы курлом

Comment: какая разница апи или нет. рейтлимит стоит да и все.

Comment: Большая разница. Один белый, другой черный. Разницу видешь? И в этом разница имеется.

Comment: И в чем состоит большая разница? Предположим что Вы отправляете 300 запросов в секунду с одного айпи, логично что так как они были отправлены с одного айпи адреса, их количество может быть ограничено, так как это один пользователь, отправил не совсем здоровое количество запросов в одну единицу времени. Не важно обращаетесь Вы к АПИ или просто спамите какой-то сайт cURL-ом, это HTTP запрос в любом случае. Это может быть воспринято как брутфорс или DDoS.